# Is there any system(application) variable in Qt which keeps track of whether the application is being used first time

Tags: qt

I wan’t to display a message, only on the first usage of application, i.e. a piece of code should be executed only once, when application is first time invoked. I tried using QSettings, but couldn’t work out any way.

```
if(firstTime)
   {
      //do something!
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check QSettings for some value at launch. If it doesn't exist, then its a first launch. After that, set the variable so it will be found each subsequent load.

In PyQt4 it would look like this (I am sure you can translate to C++):

```
settings = QSettings("foo.plist", QSettings.NativeFormat)

if not settings.contains('hasLaunched'):
    # this is our first time! Weee

# no matter what, set the value for the future
settings.setValue('hasLaunched', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of "hasLaunched" you may use "lastLaunchedVersion" and store there version number. This way you may easily do some vesion specific steps on each upgrade if they are required and also detect first launch.

Answer (score 0):

In cpp:

```
// Setup the QSettings variable
QSettings settings("Organization", "ApplicationName", this);

// Check if the value for "firsttime" is set, 
// and add default value to true    
if(settings.value("firsttime", true).toBool())
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Hello", "This is our first time");

// Set the value to false, because from now on its not the first time
settings.setValue("firsttime", false);
```